# angularjs javascript ng-bind-html not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to produce a dynamic page where the contents can change without the possibility of defining templates (in theory, there can be infinite templates).

Here is the code I'm testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="Test">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="with=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Single Page Web Application </title>
    <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Test.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="TestController">

    <button onClick="Set_HTML_1()">Set HTML 1</Button>
    <button onClick="Set_HTML_2()">Set HTML 2</Button>
    <br>
    After this line comes the dynamic HTML...
    <br>
    <div ng-bind-html="This_HTML_Text">
    </div>
    <br>
    Above this line comes the dynamic HTML...

</body>
```

and the controller:

```
var Test = angular.module( 'Test', ['ngRoute']) ;

Test.controller('TestController' , ['$scope' , '$log' , '$location' , '$sce' , 
                                    function( $scope , $log , $location , $sce) {

    console.log("In controller TestController");


    Set_HTML_1 = function () {

        var dummy = "<h1> This is the header when clicking on second buton </h1><br>" + 
                    "<button onClick=\"alert('Hi from 1');\">Click me</Button>" ;

        console.log("Deploying " + dummy);

        $scope.This_HTML_Text = $sce.trustAsHtml(dummy) ;

    }

    Set_HTML_2 = function () {

        var dummy = "<h1> This is the header when clicking on second buton </h1><br>" + 
                    "<button onClick=\"alert('Hi from 2');\">Click me</Button>" ;

        console.log("Deploying " + dummy);

        $scope.This_HTML_Text = $sce.trustAsHtml(dummy) ;

    }

} 

]) ;
```

When clicking at any of the two buttons (i.e. "Set HTML 1" or "Set HTML 2") I see in the console that there are no errors and the functions are invoked, but nothing is presented within the page.
Moreover, and as shown in the example, the generated code includes a button that needs to be operational upon rendering completion.
Any clue why it is not working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you used to bind the handlers is incorrect. Use `ng-click`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="Test">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="with=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Single Page Web Application </title>
    <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Public_Libs/Angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Test.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="TestController">

    <button ng-click="Set_HTML_1()">Set HTML 1</Button>
    <button ng-click="Set_HTML_2()">Set HTML 2</Button>
    <br>
    After this line comes the dynamic HTML...
    <br>
    <div ng-bind-html="This_HTML_Text">
    </div>
    <br>
    Above this line comes the dynamic HTML...

</body>
```

And

```
var Test = angular.module( 'Test', ['ngRoute']) ;

Test.controller('TestController' , ['$scope' , '$log' , '$location' , '$sce' , 
                                    function( $scope , $log , $location , $sce) {

    console.log("In controller TestController");


    $scope.Set_HTML_1 = function () {

        var dummy = "<h1> This is the header when clicking on second buton </h1><br>" + 
                    "<button onClick=\"alert('Hi from 1');\">Click me</Button>" ;

        console.log("Deploying " + dummy);

        $scope.This_HTML_Text = $sce.trustAsHtml(dummy) ;

    }

    $scope.Set_HTML_2 = function () {

        var dummy = "<h1> This is the header when clicking on second buton </h1><br>" + 
                    "<button onClick=\"alert('Hi from 2');\">Click me</Button>" ;

        console.log("Deploying " + dummy);

        $scope.This_HTML_Text = $sce.trustAsHtml(dummy) ;

    }

} 

]) ;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response and solution. Indeed, things work after the suggested change. Still, the code I submitted is a very simplified example of what I need. In my real situation, I am constructing tables. My problem is that I cannot reach the point in which clicking on a row would trigger an event (so I can do something with the selected row). In any case, I'm gladly voting for your answer. THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Hello again @tcooc. I tried the solution in my real application and it still does not work. The main difference with the sample of above is that I'm also using bootstrap. Are you aware of any compatibility issues (AngularJS and Bootstrap) that could prevent the page from being updated? Thanks again.